# 400 BAD REQUEST when POST using mockapi.io in Next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js13

I'm trying to create board title by calling mockapi endpoint, but I keep getting a 400 bad request
and I'm also wondering how can I use server actions with mockApi.io in next.js? or I only have to use API route in that case?

this is a code snippet

```
//app/(platform)/(dashborad)/organization/[organizationId]/page.tsx

"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

const OrganizationIdPage = () => {
  const [boardTitle, setBoardTitle] = useState("");

  const createBoard = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const submitData = { title: boardTitle };
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://65ae7ed21dfbae409a74f76c.mockapi.io/api/v1/board",
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(submitData),
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      console.log("the response is:", res);
      if (res.ok) {
        console.log("Went through");
      } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to create the board");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    setBoardTitle(" ");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={createBoard}>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title"
          name="title"
          required
          placeholder="Enter a board title"
          className="border-input border p-1"
          onChange={(e) => setBoardTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="btn-primary">
          Create Board
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default OrganizationIdPage;
```

also this is the mockApi.io config

[image: mockapi configuration screenshot]

Comment: What does your Mock API configuration look like? What does it expect for the `board` [resource](https://github.com/mockapi-io/docs/wiki/Quick-start-guide#resources)?

Comment: Looks to me like you simply used `e.target.title` when you meant `e.target.value`. Also, you cannot use inline `//` comments within a JSX element tag

Comment: @Phil, I have a title -> string and boardId -> Faker.js -> datatype.uuid

Comment: If your field is `title`, why are you using the key `boardTitle`?

Comment: @Phil because I'm using state hook

Comment: I think you misunderstood. If your Mock API resource expects a field named `title`, you should be using `const submitData = { title: boardTitle }`. You also need to fix up your `onChange` function to use `e.target.value`. This question can be closed as a series of **typos**

Comment: @Phil, used your fixes but the error still remains

Comment: Your screenshot shows the resource name is `borad`. You need to check your spelling